# How to detect what unit someone is typing in an input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to detect what unit someone is typing in a free text input field. For example, if they type `100 kg` I want to detect that it's `weight`. If they type in `100 liter`, it should detect `volume` and so on. I want it to work for different styles of input. For example, `100kg` and `100 kg` should both be detected as weight.

This is how I have currently built it. It works for simple examples, but it has some problems:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { observer } from "mobx-react";


@observer
export default class DemoComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputValue: "",
            unit: "no unit detected",
        }
    }

    updateInputValue(e) {
        let unit = this.detectUnit(e.target.value);
        if(unit) {
            this.setState({unit: unit,inputValue: e.target.value});
        } else {
            this.setState({unit: "no unit detected",inputValue: 
            e.target.value})
        }
    }

    detectUnit(string) {
        let currentUnit = false;
        let cleanedString = string.toLowerCase();
        for (let unit in units) {
            if (units.hasOwnProperty(unit)) {
                // do stuff
                for(let i = 0; i < units[unit].length ; i++) {
                    if(cleanedString.includes(units[unit][i])) {
                        currentUnit = unit;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(currentUnit)
        return currentUnit;        
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="testID">
                <h1 className="democss">{this.props.title}</h1>
            <div className="container">
                <input value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={(e) => 
                this.updateInputValue(e)} />
                <h2 className="unit">{this.state.unit}</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const units = {
    velocity: ["m/s","km/h","meter/s","m/sekund", "meter/sekund",],
    weight: ["kg","kilogram","kilo gram","kgram","k gram","kilo","k"],
    volume: ["liter",], //add "l" later
}
```

If I type in `randomliter`, it will detect that as volume because the string `liter` exists. How do I fix that so it only checks for exact match while still being able to accept multiple styles of input like

`100kg` `100 kg` `kg 100`

and detect them all as weight?
Is this something I could use regex for? The key point is that they can enter a value and unit freely, and I need to detect the value and unit.

Comment: You're using `includes()`.  You probably should exact-match the string instead.  Or perhaps do a word match.

Comment: You don't really need `if (units.hasOwnProperty(unit))` if you're using `for..in`. You can assume `units` does have each property showing up in the iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `match` with a regular expression instead of `includes`.

The following should do about what you want for the kg example.

```
regex = '^[0-9]*\s*kg\s*[0-9]*$'
cleanedString.match(regex)
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/znT89B/2) for demo/explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

> **EDIT: Mad's answer is better.** If you were simply comparing 'randomLiter' to 'liter' my answer below would be better, but you are comparing '100 randomLiters' to 'liter', which makes Mad's approach of using RegEx more applicable. I'll just leave the answer below for posterity.

Instead of checking whether each item in the `unit` array exists in `cleanedString`, do it the other way around, and check whether `cleanedString` exists in the `unit` array:

That is, instead of this:

```
for (let unit in units) {
    if (units.hasOwnProperty(unit)) {
        // do stuff
        for(let i = 0; i < units[unit].length ; i++) {
            if(cleanedString.includes(units[unit][i])) {
                currentUnit = unit;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...do this:

```
for (let unit in units) {
    if(units[unit].includes(cleanedString)){
        currentUnit = unit
        break
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `units[unit]` is an array of strings.
- `units[unit][i]` is a string.
- `cleanedString` is a string.

`{stringA}.includes({stringB})` checks whether `stringB` is a substring of `stringA`

```
cleanedString.includes(units[unit][i]))
// ...is the same as
'randomliter'.includes('liter')
// ...which will return 'true'
```

`{array}.includes({stringB})` checks whether `stringB` *exactly matches* one of the values in `array`.

```
units[unit].includes(cleanedString)
// ...is the same as
['liter'].includes('randomliter')
// ...which will return 'false'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return the exact type :

```
const units = {
    velocity: ["m/s", "km/h", "meter/s", "m/sekund", "meter/sekund",],
    weight: ["kg", "kilogram", "kilo gram", "kgram", "k gram", "kilo", "k"],
    volume: ["liter", "l"]
}

Object.entries(units).find(([name, typos]) => typos.some(typo => inputValue.includes(typo)))
```

This function iterate over every unit type in your array and then over every different strings, if one matches, it returns the whole object.

Working example :

```js
function getUnit(inputValue){
  const units = {
    velocity: ["m/s", "km/h", "meter/s", "m/sekund", "meter/sekund",],
    weight: ["kg", "kilogram", "kilo gram", "kgram", "k gram", "kilo", "k"],
    volume: ["liter", "l"]
  }

  const result = Object.entries(units).find(([name, typos]) => typos.some(typo => inputValue.includes(typo)))

  return result ? result[0] : null
}

console.log(getUnit('450 kg'))
console.log(getUnit('4 l'))
console.log(getUnit('50 meter/s'))
console.log(getUnit('850 rfeh'))
console.log(getUnit('4.56 kgram'))
console.log(getUnit('756 liter'))
console.log(getUnit('758 meter/sekund'))
```